# Polite way to request an answer be reviewed by an asker

Tags: discussion

A while ago I answered [a question about AGAL bytecode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18200136/whats-the-agal-tex-syntax/23764597#23764597). The answer covers the entirety of the question asked, and is assuredly correct. The asker has yet to accept the answer or comment regarding how they feel it could be improved. Is there a polite/standard way of asking for their feedback?

Comment: Nine months is a long time to wait for an answer, you can't assume the guy is still trying to solve the problem.  Hopefully somebody else will google it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Posting an answer automatically notifies the question author without you having to do anything.  There is no need to try to notify them again, nor is it polite to be begging the question author to accept your answer.  They can if they want, and if they don't want to, that's *entirely fine*.

Comment: ...albeit frustrating. Unfortunate that all the obvious ways to incentivize answering, besides those already implemented, would probably be ripe for misuse. C'est la vie, I guess?

Comment: @Nate Sounds like you're more concerned with getting Imaginary Internet Points than you are with posting quality content that improves the programming community.

Comment: Not really. The increased permissions are nice, but I haven't had any trouble acquiring them; the participate -> gain privileges model works for me. That said: the goal of SE (correct me if I'm wrong) is to provide answers for peoples' questions as well as allowing future readers to benefit from the exchange. When I look at old questions, I'm wary of lone, unaccepted answers... I don't want future readers to assume I'm incorrect or misleading.

Comment: Reread my question - I specifically stated I wanted to improve my answer if it was somehow lacking. I personally would not mind if someone did this to me, though I cede that I am not everyone. I suggest you stop addressing me as though I had some nefarious intent - I did not.

Comment: @Nate If the author or anyone else reads your answer and finds it lacking they'll provide that feedback all on their own without you needing to ask them to accept your answer to get it.

Comment: I don't think you understand what I mean, but it's not really all that important. Thank you for the info regarding SE's site functionality - the rest is/was extraneous.